# Compare Directory Tree

Tags: 13.04, directory

Does there exist a tool that compare Directory tree (Files. sub dirs) and show you waht is missing. I have an upload too which I'm coding and would like to see if it does not mess with structure.

Nothing big just show me how does directory X compare with Y

To clarify more here is an example

The tree

```
Dir1+
     +Subdir1
     +sudir2
        +File1
        +File2
```

and the tree

```
Dir1+
     +Subdir1
     +sudir2
        +File1
        +File2
```

are the same but tree

```
Dir1+
     +Subdir1
     +sudir2
        +File1
        +File2
```

and tree

```
Dir1+
     +Subdir1
     +sudir2
        +File1
        +File3
```

Should show me that File2 is missing and File3 is added.

Does such a tool exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A less technical approach would be to use gui synchronization software such as **FreeFileSync**
(Visual folder comparison and synchronization)

There is a ppa at [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~freefilesync/+archive/ffs):

Put these lines in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freefilesync/ffs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freefilesync
```

I've successfully been using this tool for a few years now to back-up and/or sync folders on Windows and Ubuntu.

See this screenshot I set-up displaying what it would do in your situation:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) is a very good graphical diff tool (and more):

```
meld dir1 dir2 &
```

[image]

Comment: I will give it a try. Hope it does all I have posted above!

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo yes it does and it is a part of the standard repository so can be installed just like `sudo apt install meld`

Comment: **be aware of RAM** though, for comparing 2 bigger directory trees (around 10000 files vs 6000files) (real user data, nothing funky), it ate almost 20GBs of RAM x)

Answer (score 10):

`diff` can compare directory trees, too.

```
diff <dir1> <dir2>
```

Or if you don't want to see the files content differences:

```
diff -q <dir1> <dir2>
```

Some graphical tools available in Ubuntu repos: dirdiff, fldiff, kdiff3, meld, mgdiff.

Comment: For a tree comparison, you need to go recursive. You need the `-r` option or it will be wrong. Could be a disaster too.

Comment: It has nice readable params `diff --brief --recursive  dir/one dir/two` too if you like to understand what you are doing, brief: "report only when files differ"